# How can we replace iptables with firewalld in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, software-installation, iptables, firewalld

In Ubuntu 16.04, can we install firewalld services?

Comment: Doesn't firewalld depend on iptables?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To switch do the following:

1. Stop iptables if in use:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop iptables
   ```
2. Make sure *iptables* are not used by your system anymore:

   ```
   sudo systemctl mask iptables
   ```
3. Check its status:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status iptables
   ```
4. Remove *UFW* if installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ufw
   ```

Firewalld - **Dynamic Firewall Manager**

This replaces *iptable* as the preferred way to manage your firewall. Commands to use with *firewalld* includes:

1. Install `firewalld`:

   ```
   sudo apt install firewalld
   ```
2. Check its status:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status firewalld
   ```
3. Enable or disable *firewalld*:

   ```
   sudo systemctl [enable | disable ] firewalld
   ```
4. Starting and stoping it:

   ```
   sudo systemctl [ start | stop ] firewalld
   ```

So to use it is simply to enable it as in *steps 2*, then use the *man pages* to get more information.

See [here](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/) for more information on how to use *firewalld*

Comment: You left out

   "apt install firewalld"

in the Firewalld section - it's not included in Ubuntu 16.04 by default