# Is there a Firewall for Ubuntu which doesn't need to be turned on at every reboot like Gufw

Tags: firewall

Gufw turns itself off at every reboot.
I've entered all the commands in terminals.... sudo systemctl enable ufw
sudo systemctl start ufw and so on. 
This is a major security risk. 
Why has a firewall been provided which switches itself off? 
Is there another firewall which works as would be expected?
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Well, there's one alternative https://askubuntu.com/a/7783/295286 Never tried it myself, though, so can't recommend.

Comment: I believe that with `ufw` you actually have to use `sudo ufw enable` from the command line to turn it on, and `sudo ufw disable` to turn it off.  Also, you can check the status with `sudo ufw status` and you can check with the `systemctl status ufw.service`.

Comment: You've got something configured wrong. ufw doesn't turn off on any of my systems.  Also note: gufw is not the firewall, ufw is. gufw is just the configuration interface.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, there is no need to switch it on. The solution to your questions for ufw can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22667/why-is-the-firewall-disabled-by-default/).
More informations you found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw). The normal behavior is if it's enabled it keeps enabled after reboot. To try another, maybe this fits your need [firewalld](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864958/how-can-we-replace-iptables-with-firewalld-in-ubuntu-16-04).

And it's described in the gufw UI.

[image]