# Iptables reload/restart on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I have problem with iptables on Ubuntu 18.04 before that I used to use with Centos 7 and Red Hat and I can simply restart with

```
systemctl restart iptables
```

but on Ubuntu it does not work. I could not find iptable under `init.d` neither.

Can anybody help me out how can I restart or reload it on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: So ubuntu 1804 delete iptables-save from the default installation? I used to spend serval days to study how to use iptables-save, then it is disappear from the default installation, WTF? So which linux kernel syscall should I use to get the same effect as iptables-save in case ubuntu 2004 delete ufw from the default installation?

Answer (score 41):

EDIT: Newer versions of RHEL use `firewalld` by default, which is also available in Ubuntu.

If you would like your Ubuntu firewall to function in a similar way to RedHat/Fedora, in Ubuntu 18.04 20.04 22.04, you probably want these:

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent
```

Then edit the rules in `/etc/iptables/rules.v[46]`

Other commands that might be useful:

```
netfilter-persistent save
netfilter-persistent start

iptables-save  > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6

systemctl stop    netfilter-persistent
systemctl start   netfilter-persistent
systemctl restart netfilter-persistent
```

If you ever find that your rules aren't correctly applied at boot, you can run these commands to test that there are not errors in your config files:

```
iptables-restore  < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

The two packages are similar, but provide slightly different functionality. If you only install `iptables-persistent`, you won't get the service definition file for correct handling in systemd, eg `/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service`

If you only install `netfilter-persistent`, you will find that rules are not correctly applied at boot, as per the README

```
netfilter-persistent and its plugins
------------------------------------

netfilter-persistent does no work on its own. You need the accompanying
plugins (for example, iptables-persistent) to load and save filter rules.

However, commands are run from netfilter-persistent. For example, to save
all filter rules:

   netfilter-persistent save

or to load them:

   netfilter-persistent start

For more details, see `man netfilter-persistent`.

The system service will try to load rules at startup if enabled, but by
default it will not flush rules at shutdown. This behaviour can be changed
by editing /etc/default/netfilter-persistent.
```

Comment: afaict, `netfilter-persistent save` will also update `/etc/iptables/rules.v4/6`, which if correct, I think noting `iptables-save  > /etc/iptables/rules.v4/6` as well is unnecessary.

Comment: That is true, but the additional commands were included for completeness. Personally, I never use the `netfilter-persistent save` command because it includes comments and doesn't zero the counters.

Answer (score 5):

In newer distributions you normally have a frontend to configure and manage the firewall. The most popular these days are `ufw` and `firewalld` and maybe `shorewall`. Those frontends also take care to add the rules in `iptables` and the `iptables` script can be skipped or better to say should be skipped, as the frontends will not pick up your changes you have done with `iptables` command directly.

For Ubuntu 18.04, it seems `firewalld` has become the default where `ufw` is installed but inactive.

```
root@localhost:~# firewall-cmd --state 
running
root@localhost:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

So rather than creating own `iptables` conform rules you should use these frontends to create your firewall configuration.

I am not familiar with `ufw` but sure you will find information here with askubuntu or somewhere else on the internet.
`firewalld` comes with a GUI (`firewall-config`) and a command line tool `firewall-cmd`.
With `firewalld` you have the option to add rules without applying it right now (*permanent*) and apply it only after a firewall reload. Or you can add them to your *runtime* configuration, test it and add it then to your permanent configuration.
To reload e.g. a newly added *permanent* configuration to your *running* rules you would have to enter the command as follows or do the corresponding clicks in the GUI.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

It might look a bit more complicated on the first glance, since `firewalld` is following *zones* and an *chains* concept. But it nicely integrates with *NetworkManager*, ships a GUI...
A good starting point to get familiar with it is [here](https://firewalld.org/documentation/).

Comment: That does not answer the question

Comment: That might work but can’t automate using front end apps for DevOps.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04, it seems that firewalld is NOT installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can check content of the package with :

```
dpkg -L iptables-persistent
```

And then you will find that following command is correct:

```
/etc/init.d/netfilter-persistent restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 1804 to achieve persistence, use the command:
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

or just add the iptables line by hand to the file: /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Answer (score -2):

Debian / Ubuntu does not have an init script for iptables (unlike any fedora / RHEL / Centos)

You either have e to write a script or see [iptables resets when server reboots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84781/iptables-resets-when-server-reboots)

Alternately use UFW https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Or firewalld

[How can we replace iptables with firewalld in ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864958/how-can-we-replace-iptables-with-firewalld-in-ubuntu-16-04)