# IPtables not restored

Tags: networking, iptables

I installed iptables and iptables-persistent in order to save the rules and apply them after reboot, however whenever I try to restore or save I get this errors:

1. with `sudo netfilter-persistent save` : `usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables: 45: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables: /sbin/modprobe: not found`
2. with `sudo netfilter-persistent reload` after reboot:  the rules were not saved so it does not block with my rule: `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -i eno1 -j DROP`
3. I've tried to save with `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 && ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6` but it doesn't seem to add the rule, and after reboot
4. `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` sends: `Bad argument '[unsupported' Error occurred at line: 30`

my Ubuntu version is 18, please help save rules after reboot

EDIT: my error on 2: `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables: 45: /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables: /sbin/modprobe: not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem regrading 1&2: You need reinstall the module of modprode, read more here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iptables-persistent/+bug/1820144

Basically just install `apt-get --reinstall install module-init-tools` before `apt install -y iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Regarding number 4: The error message you have received is quite specific - there appears to be an error on line 30 of `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`. If there is an error in this file, then the rules will not load at boot.

Make sure you have `iptables-persistent` and `netfilter-persistent` to ensure that this works properly. I wrote a good write up of this here: [Iptables reload/restart on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052919)

Comment: I didn't install both, I'll try that now on my docker, I also want to make sure of something- I tried to  `subprocess.call` to `sudo netfilter-persistent reload` right as the system boots (added that to a script that runs as it boots), will that affect?